# No password supplied error from osm2pgsql

Tags: osm2pgsql

I want to load some power data to a database I have created in postgres (postgis). But when type the following command in the terminal (ubuntu 18.04) I ended up with the following error.

`osm2pgsql -r pbf --username=postgres --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --database=de_power_160718 --style power.style -s -C cash_size_in_MB --number-processes nb-processors de_power_160718.osm.pbf`

The error I ended up with.

`Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Connection to database failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

I didn't ended-up with a prompt to input the password which is usually the case. Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a password prompt, you must use the `-W` or `--password` [option](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#database-options)